# Strange NSURLConnection caching behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I have a simple method that takes a url and loads it from the server:

```
- (void)loadURL:(NSString*)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
}
```

The server returns a response with max-age of 1 day.

Problem is that when I run these 3 lines repeatedly, 2 of them randomly miss the cache and reload the response:

```
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51bdbc73808897302f000001/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51ee9d4e263d08fe04000003/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51d17b81de38c60b20000006/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww"];
```

If I add some random unique data (&x, &y, &z) to each request's query string it fixes the problem:

```
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51bdbc73808897302f000001/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww&x"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51ee9d4e263d08fe04000003/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww&y"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51d17b81de38c60b20000006/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww&z"];
```

Also, if I reduce the length of query strings to 80 chars it fixes the problem as well:

```
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51bdbc73808897302f000001/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09Royipm"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51ee9d4e263d08fe04000003/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09Royipm"];
[self loadURL:@"http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51d17b81de38c60b20000006/avatar?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09Royipm"];
```

What's going on?
Is this a bug in iOS? How can I fix it?

P.S: I've tested this in an empty application with no extra stuff both on iOS 5 and 6.

Comment: How do you verify whether the URL loading system reads from the cache or accesses the remote server? What cache-control headers are set in the request? Does the client use a cache at all? Note that a cache may ignore a server's specified expiration time.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I run 'tail -f server.log | grep avatar' to see requests in realtime as they come in. Server sets the Cache-Control header with a value of 'max-age=86400'. And the client has NSURLCache set.

Comment: You need to check the cache-control headers from the request. As mentioned, a client can ignore the expiration date set from a server or proxy. Caching is quite complex: [13 Caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)

Comment: You might also see "cache validating" in your server logs, whose status code then is usually 304 with no entity body.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper There are no cache related headers in the request. I know about complexities of caching but I need to know why NSURLConnection's behavior changes based on the url.

Comment: So, my guess is - which certainly requires more investigation of the issue, and under the assumption that the client is _actually NOT_ sending a "validating request" but a normal unconditional GET and the server responds normally: the URL cache may not save the full URL including the complete query string. Thus, a query to the URL cache with the original URL as parameter will not find an entry. However, this explains not all of your observations. :/

Comment: To confirm that, we would need to inspect the URL cache (which is a SQLite database).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I think it's OK for the client not to send a validating request until the cached response is expired when cache policy is set to the default value of NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy. BTW I checked the Cache.db file and its cfurl_cache_response table has a request_key key which includes the full url. It's not truncated.

Comment: Try adding an image extension to the url like this: `http://192.168.0.105:8080/users/51bdbc73808897302f000001/avatar.jpg?size=200x200&access_token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzp77eDLqub3EWfXGe4c09RoyipmXgcENwfE6EV9yzvgp5VTSZww`, maybe it fixes the behavior for the image caching.

Comment: @Shahin Thank you but it didn't work.

Comment: @soheilpro I agree fully that there should no "validation request" unless cache headers require a re-validation and if the cached entity is "fresh enough" (this is in accordance to point 2 in §13.1.1 in RFC 2616). Since there is also no URL issue (normalization, etc.) the issue becomes more "interesting" ;)  I would suggest to implement the asynchronous style with delegates, and check the cached response in `connection:willCacheResponse:`. Also try to fetch the response via `cachedResponseForRequest:` once it is saved and test if there are any issues.

Comment: @soheilpro Also test, if - once you should have a valid local cached response - whether the cache returns a response when the server is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Set the caching behaviour in the `NSURLRequest` with `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`. Try:

```
- (void)loadURL:(NSString*)url
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
}
```

Possibly also use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` for `cachePolicy`.

Comment: This would change the cache policy in that it bypasses it, but does not explain why the cache is not used sometimes when it should.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use ASIHTTPRequest instead 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/